# Visual Studio Apache Cordova Remote Build on Mac not working

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, apache-cordova

I am working on a Apache Cardova application using Visual Studio 2015 update 3 on a Windows System. The application is easily built on android, both emulator and device.

I am unable to build the app for IOS devices.

Following the instructions for IOS build, i have done the following

1. Installed xCode on a Mac
2. Installed npm, xCode command line utlities and all other tools required.
3. Started RemoteBuild agent on Mac.
4. From visual studio connected to this Mac using the pin generated by remote build agent.(secure connection| I am unable to use unsecure connection)

I am able to build for Ios on Ripple.

But when I try to build using  >>Debug | Ios | Remote Device
I get the following error

> Error      Error: Module did not self-register.

Diagnostic error message

> MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: Module did not self-register.
>   Error Module did not self-register. (TaskId:9)
>   Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED. (TaskId:9)

The remote agent runs on the mac but shows to update.

Comment: I suggest try to use Cordova cli inside mac to create Cordova project , and transfer the project there, it is easier than using VS build the project.

Comment: Can you post the full build output? It seems like something is not installing correctly. What version of Node/npm are you on?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what went wrong but the issue got resolved.
This is what i did

1. Updated Apache Cordova to the latest version in my project
2. Cleared the Cordova Cache from Tools>Options>Tools For Apache Cordova> Clear   Cache
3. It still did not work.....but when I restarted my PC the next day..MAGIC. Everything was working fine.

I don't know how exactly the issue got resolved. But at least its working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for #3. It will work with a restart but all that needs to be restarted is Visual Studio. Glad you figured it out :)